# Any good editor for gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, code-editor

I have been looking for good gnuplot editor for a while without success.
I am using the gedit with gnuplot syntax highlight plugin, but it doen't work well. 
Does anyone know a good editor though?

Answer (score 6):

I use gedit (Linux only, I think), that has a good support for syntax highlighting for any language. I remember I had to manually add an additional highlighting file that can be [downloaded here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GtkSourceView/LanguageDefinitions), but maybe current versions include that file.

You can [checkout here](http://apurbapaul.blogspot.fr/2014/09/colour-highlighting-gnuplot-code-in.html) for some technical details.

**Edit**: Once you have downloaded the `gnuplot.lang` file, just run these two commands and restart gedit (From [bugs.debian.org](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=602208#10)). Works perfectly.

```
sudo cp gnuplot.lang /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/
sudo chmod 644 /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/gnuplot.lang
```

Answer (score 4):

I really like of [`Notepad++`](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) with `RunMe` plugin and [`VS Code`](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with [`Code Runner`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner), [`Rainbow Brackets`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=2gua.rainbow-brackets) and [`Gnuplot`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MarioSchwalbe.gnuplot) extensions.

---

**Notepad ++**

[image: Notepad++ as gnuplot editor]

---

**VS Code**

[image: VS Code as gnuplot editor]

Comment: Please, tell us how you made gnuplot syntax highlighting in Notepad++

Comment: Sorry for a delayed answer. I've use a custom one. See `Language » User Defined Language » Define your language…` option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some of these

http://linux.softpedia.com/downloadTag/Gnuplot+GUI

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jgp/

But, I use vim with gnuplot syntax highlighting plugin

Comment: The first link is broken.

Comment: This is the right link @foad
https://linux.softpedia.com/get/Science/GPlot-8126.shtml

Comment: [GPlot](http://gplot.sourceforge.net/) is not a gnuplot GUI but a Perl Wrapper of the language. Plus when a software an official repository why would someone link to spyware distribution website?!

Answer (score 1):

I am generally very happy with using vim. There aren't a lot of editors that recognize gnuplot syntax.

The gnuplot syntax highlighting built in to vim is out of date (missing lots of recent keywords), but I made an updated version available here: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4873

Answer (score 0):

This might be an off-topic question but some of the interesting editors for gnuplot are:

1. [Gnuplot Editor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gpedit/):

```
            
                       image courtesy of sourceforge.net.
```

2. [Cirkuit](https://wwwu.uni-klu.ac.at/magostin/cirkuit.html):

```
            
        image courtesy of Matteo Agostinelli Alpen-Adria-Universität Klagenfurt.
```

**P.S.** [Jupyter](https://github.com/has2k1/gnuplot_kernel) and [Cantor-LabPlot](https://labplot.kde.org/2019/08/15/cantor-19-08/) can also be used as gnuplot interfaces.